# Google script macro to save a single sheet in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I've created this code, for saving a spreadsheet in a folder of googledrive. It works correctly. I use this like a macro in my spreadsheet.

```
function mysave() {
 var folder3 =DriveApp.getFoldersByName("NAME_OF_FOLDER").next().getId();
 var folder3_sel =DriveApp.getFolderById(folder3);
 DriveApp.getFileById("ID_OF_SPREADSHEET").makeCopy("TEST",folder3_sel);
```

But I would like a code for saving a SINGLE SHEET of the SPREADSHEET in a folder of googledrive. I can't use the ID of the sheet, because it doesn't work with "driveapp.". I need to find another way to save the sheet.
Can anyone help me? I'm not a programmer.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new spreadsheet and just moving the sheet there:

```
function mySave() {

  const newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(`TEST`)

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                .getSheetByName(`SheetToCopy`)
                .copyTo(newSpreadsheet)

  SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSpreadsheet.getId())
                .deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`))

  const folder3 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("NAME_OF_FOLDER").next().getId()

  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId())
          .moveTo(folder3)

}
```

And of course, if you need anything explained I would be more than happy.

Comment: Thank you for the help! But I think I'm missing some permissions. 
"Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.create. Required permissions: googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

In these days I'm trying to get API auth, on API console. I want to open the project (GCP)with the correct permission in appscript. Is it the correct way?
Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know this was for GCP.. I'm not familiar with it; but you must be able to add SpreadsheetApp permissions to a manifest?

Comment: Manifest was the problem, I read a lot of topic and nobody spoke about that. Thank you so much, now I fixed and I can work with these function.
 
About your code this is the problem:  The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo.   

So I try to get Id of the sheet but it doesn't work the same.

Comment: @crisis Ah, my apologies, I have updated the code. `.copyTo(newSpreadsheet.getId())` should be `.copyTo(newSpreadsheet)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect, fix.

Now this error, only for the moving:

```
  const folder3 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("my_folder").next().getId()

  const newSpreadsheet_id= newSpreadsheet.getId()

  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet_id)
          .moveTo(folder3) }
```

Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.File.moveTo.

or

```
const folder3_id = Driveapp.getFolderById("folder_id")
  
  const newSpreadsheet_id= newSpreadsheet.getId()

  DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet_id)
          .moveTo() (folder3_id)
```

ReferenceError: Driveapp is not defined (error in folder3_id)

Problem with parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested, I fixed in this way:

```
    function mysave() {

  const newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(`TEST`)
  const id_newSpreadsheet = newSpreadsheet.getId()
  

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                .getSheetByName(`sheet_to_copy`)
                .copyTo(newSpreadsheet)
                



  SpreadsheetApp.openById(newSpreadsheet_id)
                .deleteSheet(newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`))
                

  const folder3 = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("my_folder").next().getId()
  
  var sheet = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet_id)

  DriveApp.getFolderById(folder3).addFile(sheet)
```

Thank you @NEWAZA for help